# Mvc 4 Jquery Jtable: how to change font size of columns In .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jtable

I am using MVC 4, Jquery, Jtable. I need to decrease font size of the columns title.  There are a lot of examples for Java, however I could not find anything for .NET.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit jtable.css. Check for div.jtable-main-container > table.jtable > thead th.
You can change properties there.